# Maintaining localization using custom mvc routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm implementing some code for localization in asp.net mvc 5 using code from this blog entry

[localization-in-asp.net-mvc](http://blogs.shaunxu.me/archive/2012/09/04/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-upgraded.aspx)

This code is what Im posting about:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
          Constants.ROUTE_NAME, // Route name
         string.Format("{{{0}}}/{{controller}}/{{action}}/{{id}}", Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG), // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  :     );
```

Its in a custom Register_Routes method called before the regular Register_Routes method.

Its easy enough to create a dropdown to change locale to supply urls to match the route above for the current url: i.e from /en-US/Admin to /ro-RO/Admin.

But what I dont get is how to maintain those Urls once using a given locale.

So if i navigate to /en-US/Admin, and then switch culture from my dropdown to Romanian it will post back and I will be at /ro-RO/Admin. Great but say the Admin page has a link on it to /Example. I now want that to be /ro-RO/Example instead of /en-US/Example so obviously Im not going to want to use literal links they need to generated on the fly as culture aware.

The example goes on to use this:

```
public class LocalizationControllerHelper
   {
        public static void OnBeginExecuteCore(Controller controller)
      {
          if (controller.RouteData.Values[Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG] != null &&
               !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controller.RouteData.Values[Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG].ToString()))
            {
                // set the culture from the route data (url)
                var lang = controller.RouteData.Values[Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG].ToString();
              Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
           }
           else
           {
               // load the culture info from the cookie
               var cookie = controller.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.COOKIE_NAME];
               var langHeader = string.Empty;
               if (cookie != null)
               {
                   // set the culture by the cookie content
                   langHeader = cookie.Value;
                   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(langHeader);
              }
               else
              {
                   // set the culture by the location if not speicified
                   langHeader = controller.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0];
                   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(langHeader);
              }
               // set the lang value into route data
               controller.RouteData.Values[Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG] = langHeader;
           }

           // save the location into cookie
          HttpCookie _cookie = new HttpCookie(Constants.COOKIE_NAME,     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name);
           _cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
           controller.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(_cookie);
       }
   }
```

Which is pretty straightforward: once you switch locales for a given url, it checks the url for lang param according to route and if not there it uses the value stored in the cookie.

I've seen similar route tables in other localization blogs entries, i.e. {lang} as the first param but the problem is if it's not supplied then request doesn't route at all since for instance "Home" is not a known culture. Also Google seems to advise against storing culture in a cookie re: SEO.

So I want my cultures in the Url just like MSDN.

So it seems Im missing a piece re: injecting culture into Urls.  Should I be creating a custom html helper extension to generate action links with the current culture embedded as first param?

That what Im about to do, but for the example code to have come so far and then not do this, I wonder if Im misusing it? And since I see other blog posts doing the same/similar things :re{lang} as first param but none of them providing any way to generate links after the user has switched locales, I have to wonder if Im missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ActionLink helper as is and the current language in the URL is automatically included.

Examples:

```
Current URL: http://localhost/en-US
ActionLink:  @Html.ActionLink("Create Account", "Register", "Account")
Generated link: http://localhost/en-US/Account/Register

Current URL: http://localhost:12751/es-MX/Account/Login
ActionLink:  @Html.ActionLink("Create Account", "Register", "Account")
Generated link: http://localhost/es-MX/Account/Register
```

ActionLink keeps the current values (lang in this before) before the controller.